# Event bubbling inside UserControl in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp

I've created a custom `UserControl`, it's a button with a grid inside it.

From the Page that contains it, `MainPage.xaml`, I need to bind a `Click` event to the UserControl, and the function for the `EventHandler` must be written outside, in the MainPage (not inside the UserControl).

So, reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192739/how-do-i-raise-an-event-in-a-usercontrol-and-catch-it-in-mainpage), I've created an Event and a EventHandler function that triggers the event. These are inside the UserControl. 
This are the classes

**UserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public class MyButton : UserControl
{
   public event RoutedEventHandler ButtonClicked;

       private void ButtonClickedHandler()
       {
        //Null check makes sure the main page is attached to the event
        if (this.ButtonClicked != null)
            this.ButtonClicked(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        Debug.WriteLine("ButtonClickedHandler");
       }
   }
```

---

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MyButton_Click");
        }

        private void MyButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as MyButton).ButtonClicked += MyButton_Click;
        }
```

As you can see, I've placed a couple of `Debug.WriteLine`, but they don't get triggered, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you ever call `ButtonClickedHandler()`?

Comment: Yip, @zockDoc's right by the look's of things you have forgot to call the `ButtonClickedHandler()`.

Comment: Yeah, but what was the point [in the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192739/how-do-i-raise-an-event-in-a-usercontrol-and-catch-it-in-mainpage) to make it private then?
Anyway, `Debug.WriteLine("MyButton_Click");` doesn't get triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a single method in your code that is never called by anything will not make your program work. You will first have to call the `ButtonClickedHandler()` method each time your button is clicked.
To do that, just register a method for the click-event of your button in your xaml file.

```
<Button Content="This Is Your Button" Click="YourButtonClick"/>
```

And then call the `ButtonClickedHandler()` method in there:

```
private void YourButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ButtonClickedHandler();
}
```

A simpler way to solve the problem is using an event property:

**UserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public Event RoutedEventHandler ButtonClicked 
{
    add {
        ButtonName.Click += value; //use the name of your button here
    }
    remove {
        ButtonName.Click -= value;
    }
}
```

And then you can simply register to that event in your MainWindow:

```
private void MyButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as MyButton).ButtonClicked += MyButton_Click;
}
```

By the way, I think it is better to register the event in the xaml file where you also create the control:

Comment: I've edited the UserControl like you said, and now it works! However,  I'm still trying to reconstruct the order of the operations.
First `MyButton` gets created, and when it loads, an eventHandler called `MyButton_Click` is registered to the ButtonClicked property. The `Button` inside the UserControl (let's call it `ButtonControl`) has a Click property,  `YourButtonClick`. This calls `ButtonClickedHandler()`, that adds a new Handler to `ButtonClicked` with `this.ButtonClicked(this, new RoutedEventArgs())`. `MyButton_Click` is now registered. Is this correct?

Comment: Almost. `MyButton_Click` is already registered from the moment you execute this line: `(sender as MyButton).ButtonClicked += MyButton_Click;`  
However it is only registered to the `ButtonClicked` event, which is not the same as the event that gets fired when the button within is clicked..  The method `YourButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` on the other Hand is registered to the Button within the control itself. So when the button is clicked, it is executed, calls `ButtonClickedHandler()` which then finally fires the `ButtonClicked` Event, calling the method`MyButton_Click`.

Comment: An easier way to understand the procedure is placing a breakpoint at the beginning of the program and at the start of `private void YourButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`.
With the F11 key you will then be able to see what exactly happens step by step.

Comment: I see. It's still a bit convoluted though. Isn't there a way to add a click event to the UserControl rather than going through the button within?

Comment: Well, you could also use an event property, I'll edit my answer to show you how.