# Use control's events if when it is contained in a custom control

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I created a custom object, name: `MyList`.
This Object contains a picturebox and a grid.

I need to do something if the user press on this grid, so i have to "use" `MouseDown` events of the grid.

I used this event in the MyList project (i can save in a propriety the result for example) but in hosts project can't.

I have only the `MouseDown` event of the `MyList`, so if i press on the "form" of the object, this events works, but if i press on the grid of this `MyList`.

So, i can use `MouseDown` Event of `MyList`, but how i can use Grid Events?

Comment: You need to "bubble" the event. [How do i raise an event in a usercontrol and catch it in mainpage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6192739/205233) may have answers for you.

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to expose the contained control by setting its access modifier to `Public`.